# How to give names to class instances instantiated with "for" loops?

Tags: python, class, oop

As an attribute to a certain class, I'm instantiating a bunch of objects of another class. My problem is that they have ugly names for memory addresses. How do I give them proper names?

```
class CaseReader(object):
    def __init__(self, path):
        cases_paths = glob(path + '//*')
        cases_names = os.listdir(path)
        self.case = [Case(i) for i in cases_paths]
```

Upon running:

```
a = CaseReader(path)
a
Out[4]: <__main__.CaseReader at 0x1c6dfc7fa88>
a.case
Out[5]: 
[<__main__.Case at 0x1c6dfc99fc8>,
 <__main__.Case at 0x1c6dfc99dc8>,
 <__main__.Case at 0x1c6dfcaf3c8>,
 <__main__.Case at 0x1c6dfcaf448>,
 <__main__.Case at 0x1c6dfcaf208>]
```

Comment: Have you tried overriding the `__str__()` method of the `Case` class?

Comment: Most objects in Python don't have any concept of a name. Why do you want your objects to have names?

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica It is usefull when I'm exploring the object. I want to see names cause they correspond to folders

Comment: If you want to see the folders, you can overload `Case.__repr__` so `Case('blah')` displays as `Case('blah')` instead of the default, but I would recommend against thinking of this as an object's name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overwrite the `__str__` function in the class definition and print what ever attributes you want to see, when you print the reference of the object.

Sample Code

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, name):
         self.name = name
    def __str__(self):
         return self.name
```

Comment: just incase, you need the difference between repr and str, https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/str-vs-repr-in-python/